# Jersey ClientFilter Ordering

Tags: jersey

Reading the documentation at http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e704 makes me think that `ClientFilter`s are processed in the order in which they are added.  I'm seeing the reverse, however.  Here's the code I'm testing with, similar to what's shown in the documentation:

```
ClientFilter filter1 = new ClientFilter() {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest cr) throws ClientHandlerException {
        System.out.println("Modify Request 1");
        ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(cr);
        System.out.println("Modify Response 1");
        return response;
    }
};
ClientFilter filter2 = new ClientFilter() {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest cr) throws ClientHandlerException {
        System.out.println("Modify Request 2");
        ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(cr);
        System.out.println("Modify Response 2");
        return response;
    }
};
Client c = Client.create();
c.addFilter(filter1);
c.addFilter(filter2);

ClientFilter filter3 = new ClientFilter() {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest cr) throws ClientHandlerException {
        System.out.println("Modify Request 3");
        ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(cr);
        System.out.println("Modify Response 3");
        return response;
    }
};
WebResource r = c.resource("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
r.addFilter(filter3);

System.out.println(r.get(ClientResponse.class).getStatus());
```

I would expect to see Modify Request 1 2 3, Modify Response 3 2 1, but I instead see Modify Request 3 2 1 Modify Response 1 2 3.

Am I just interpreting the documentation backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've found a bug! I've not yet decided where exactly - but we won't want (most likely) change the implementation due to backward implementation, so we might just update user guide to reflect how client filters really work (link to the user guide for reference - http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e704).

Can you file a new issue on Jersey issue tracker? http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY/

Thanks!